# PDFBox Annotations and Fonts

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox 2.0.9 and am using the PDAnnotationTextMarkup object.  I want to change the font size and color but am having difficulty.

I've tried the SetRichContent and SetAppearance but haven't had any luck using those.

Can anyone provide an example or two?  Thanks.

Comment: PDAnnotationTextMarkup don't have a font. These are Highlight, Underline, Squiggly and StrikeOut annotations.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question, show the code that you have and/or attach the PDF that you created / modified. See also the AddAnnotations.java example in the source code download.